# An integer is chosen at random from numbers 1 to 50, what is the probability that the integer chosen is a multiple of 2 or 3 or 12?

Tags: probability

I considered that multiples of 2 are represented by A, multiples of 3 by B and multiples of 12 by C.
Then I found Union of these 3 sets, which came out to be 29. 
I guess I am doing something wrong here only.
Then I found the probability  which came out to be 29/50 as total favourable outcomes are 50. 
Please someone correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: can you show me how do you obtain $29$?

Comment: Just ignore the multiples of $12$. Every multiple of $12$ is automatically a multiple of $2$ and $3$. Just do an inclusion-exclusion count of the multiples of $2$ and $3$.

Answer (score 3):

The set of multiples of 2 and the set of multiples of 3 intersect at the set of multiples of 6 (which contains the set of multiples of 12).

Let $A$ be the set of multiples of 2 in $\{1,\ldots, 50\}$, and $B$ the set of multiples of 3 in $\{1,\ldots, 50\}$. As the set of multiples of 12 in $\{1,\ldots, 50\}$ is in $A \cap B$, the set of integers in $\{1,2,\ldots, 50\}$ that is a muliple of 2, 3 or 12 is $A \cup B$.

So let us now calculate $|A \cup B|$. Note that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$. Note that $A \cap B$ the set of multiples of 6 in $\{1,\ldots, 50\}$, while $|A| = 25$ and $|B| = 16$ [make sure you see why], and $|A \cap B|$ is 8. So $|A \cup B| = 25 + 16 - 8 = 33$.

So the probability that a number drawn from $\{1,\ldots, 50\}$ according to the uniform distribution is a multiple of 2, 3, or 12 is $\frac{|A \cup B|}{50} = \frac{33}{50}$